# RLMException - RLMArray properties require a protocol defining the contained type - example: RLMArray<Person>

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I have a master realm object:

```
@interface MasterRealmObject : RLMObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) RLMArray<IDNameRealmObject *><IDNameRealmObject> *retailerType;

@property (nonatomic, strong) RLMArray<IDNameRealmObject *><IDNameRealmObject> *firmType;

@property (nonatomic, strong) RLMArray<IDNameRealmObject *><IDNameRealmObject> *businessAge;

@property (nonatomic, strong) RLMArray<StateRealmObject *><StateRealmObject> *state;

@property (nonatomic, strong) RLMArray<KYCDocsRealmObject *><KYCDocsRealmObject> *kycDocs;

@property (nonatomic, strong) RLMArray<ProofRealmObject *><ProofRealmObject> *businessDocs;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *ReligareTollFreeNumber;

@end
```

I'm trying to store values from a Dictionary as below:

```
-(void)insertMasterAPIObjects:(NSDictionary *)masterDictionary
{

    RLMRealm *realmInsertMasterObjects = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
    [realmInsertMasterObjects beginWriteTransaction];

    MasterRealmObject *masterRealm = [[MasterRealmObject alloc]init];
    masterRealm.retailerType = [masterDictionary objectForKey:@"retailer_type"];
    masterRealm.firmType = [masterDictionary objectForKey:@"firm_type"];
    masterRealm.businessAge = [masterDictionary objectForKey:@"BusinessAge"];
    masterRealm.kycDocs = [masterDictionary objectForKey:@"kyc_docs"];
    masterRealm.businessDocs = [masterDictionary objectForKey:@"business_docs"];
    masterRealm.state = [masterDictionary objectForKey:@"states"];

    [realmInsertMasterObjects addObject:masterRealm];
    [realmInsertMasterObjects commitWriteTransaction];
}
```

I'm getting this exception here on the first line in this method.

Comment: The invalid model is defined elsewhere in your code. This code runs fine for me: https://gist.github.com/jpsim/a792964b66e268fbb1aa

Comment: Thanks. The model relationship was incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

I hit a similar problem because I had omitted the

```
RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(IDNameRealmObject)
RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(StateRealmObject)
RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(KYCDocsRealmObject)
RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(ProofRealmObject)
```

macros before my @interface declaration.